# Sharepoint Designer 2007 permission issue

Tags: sharepoint-designer

While opening a site in Sharepoint Designer i am getting an error message You do not have permission to do this operation ask your website administrator to change the permission and try again. Iam the site collection administrator. Iam able to open other webapplication.

Can somebody let me know what could be the reason.

I have re installed SPD 2007 also still no luck

Thanks

Thomson

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a custom http module which does a 302 redirects to 301 . This was causing the issue. Once i removed the dll. i was able to view the sites in Sharepoint Designer

Answer (score 2):

It is possible that the farm administrator could have disabled SharePoint Designer access to the site.  Could that be what is going on?  Or are you the farm admin also?

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/940958

Comment: Iam not the farm admin, But iam able to open other web apps in the same farm

Comment: iam the site collection administrator

Answer (score 0):

Try adding yourself to the 'Owners of *sitecollectionname*' group.
It adds some extra rights to your account if I'm not mistaken.