# You do not have permission to do this operation

Tags: sharepoint-designer, permissions

I am a site collection administrator.  When I go into SharePoint Designer 2010 I can see everything. However, when I edit a Master Page, or Page Layout, I get the following error:

> You do not have permission to do this operation.  Ask your site administrator to change your permissions and then try again, or log on with a user account that has this permission. To log on with a different user account click OK.

I have made sure that all the files on the site are checked-in/approved, and still no luck.

Anyone have any ideas for things to look at, or try?

Note: This looks to be the same as this [issue](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/4739/sharepoint-designer-2007-permission-issue), just in 2010.

Comment: Where is your master page located? check your master page gallery permissions.

Answer (score 1):

I see 2 different options :

- Could it be that you disabled the SharePoint Designer in the Site Collection Advanced Settings?
- Do you have some WebApplication policy that are set on that WebApplication that would give you readonly permission ?

Comment: Could it be that you disabled the SharePoint Designer in the Site Collection Advanced Settings?
>> Nothing disabled.

Do you have some WebApplication policy that are set on that WebApplication that would give you readonly permission ?
> Will check.

Comment: Do you have some WebApplication policy that are set on that WebApplication that would give you readonly permission ?
> None that we set

Comment: You are editing from a client machine, of directly from the server ?

Comment: Editing from both a client and directly on the server produce the same result.